# f# adding element to last postition

Tags: list, f#, linked-list

```
  type Lista<'a> =
  | Data of 'a * Lista<'a> ref
  | Nil

  //let lista1 = Data(1,(ref Nil));;
  //let lista2 = Data(1,(ref (Data(2,(ref Nil)))));;
  let listaa = Data(1,(ref (Data(2,(ref (Data(3,ref Nil)))))));;
```

First position adding

```
     let zad2c list elem =
         match list with
         | Data (x1,x2) -> Data(elem, ref( Data (x1, ref (!x2))))
         | Nil -> Data(elem,ref(Nil)) ;;


         zad2c listaa 4;;
```

My main problem is adding last element to structure like this one above.
Also i have problem with removing last element.I cant find any useful thing in the internet,only LinkedList in java. Any help even some ideas will be great ;)

Comment: Are you doing this as an academic exercise? You know that lists are built-in to F#, right?

Comment: @plinth past questions asked indicate yes.

Comment: @emil Could you clarify exactly what your problem is?  "I have a problem doing x" isn't a problem statement.  You need to include more specific details like errors you're getting and examples of what you have tried up to this point.

Comment: Ye this is whole excersise.I done counting elements,adding first,return true if  specific element is in the  list,print elements.I had similar one in Java but here it is hard to find some information about f# in the Internet. @plinth i have  type Lista<'a> that doing modified LinkedList ,how i cant know Lists :D

Comment: Only solution what i can find is using head:tail and recursion.But this dont work for specific type Like this.Problem is how process this type to get last Element.

Comment: You can see how the compiler implements it here: https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L3847

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the function should take a `Lista<'a> ref` as input, together with the element to be appended, and that the append function should mutate the list and not create a new one:

```
let rec addLast el l =
    match !l with
    | Data(r, t) -> addLast el t
    | Nil -> l := Data(el, ref Nil)

let test = ref lista2
addLast 3 test
// Result:
// {contents = Data (1,{contents = Data (2,{contents = Data (3,{contents = Nil;});});});}
```

To understand what it does, look up the topics from [my previous answer to you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27136668/4191347), and also [mutable reference cells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233186.aspx).